# Delete iCloud bookmark only from a specific computer

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, safari, bookmarks

I have iCloud Safari bookmark syncing set up on two Macs and an iPhone. Is it possible to delete a bookmark (or set of bookmarks) from one machine only, so that they continue to exist on the other two devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As any changes performed to an *iCloud-Sync service* will  be pushed to all other iCloud-Sync devices, your only option would be to *unsync* the desired device form iCloud's Safari and then delete the bookmarks.

Bear in mind that once you re-enable the Safari's Sync, all of its data will be merged together.

Comment: That's actually not a bad solution; I don't make changes to my bookmarks very often. If I did need to sync them again in the future, I could just re-delete the group again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning iCloud Bookmarks Procedure:

Turn off bookmark syncing on all devices and on computer.

Clean /file /sort Safari bookmarks. Quit Safari.

Locate bookmarks.plist Safari folder in ~/Library. Drag to the desktop.

Start Safari. Bookmarks should be blank.

Turn Safari bookmarks sync back on. Let it sync to iCloud.

Quit Safari, move the ,plist back ~/Library/Safari.

Start Safari. Edited bookmark .plist is back in place. Let it sync to iCloud.